# How to give @After @Before annotation to an Interface

Tags: java, testing, annotations

I'm setting up tests and for each of them I need to do actions. I don't want to implement it in the current abstract class and want to use a Interface. I see we can set a default method. But it doesn't work properly.

I try to create `@Before` and `@After` method in the abstract class and call default method from the interface that I implemented. And this is working. But when I directly but the `@Before` and `@After` in the interface, it doesn't work.

Someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong ?

Here is my test :

```java
public class myTestClass extends AbstractTest {
    @Test
    public void myTest1 {
    System.out.println("Test List: " + myList.size());
        // ...
    }
}
```

My abstract class were I called some methods and implements the interface :

```java
public abstract class AbstractTest implements InterfaceTest {
    // ...
}
```

And here is my interface were I want to call before and after method :

```java
public interface InterfaceTest {
    List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();

    @Before
    default void before() {
        System.out.println("TEST INIT Before");
        myList.addAll(Arrays.asList("test1", "test2"));
    }

    @After
    default void after() {
        System.out.println("TEST INIT After");
        myList.clear();
    }
}
```

I expected to have :

```sh
TEST INIT Before
Test List: 2
TEST INIT After
```

But my actual result is :

```sh
Test List: 0
```

Thank you for reading

Comment: Are you aware that `List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>()` is static?

Comment: Yes it's why I clear it in each test. May be it's not the best way. The main problem is that it's not called. (Prints not called)

Comment: It is impossible, but if you use TestNG instead of JUnit it works fine.

Comment: I can't change for this project but good to know, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look into `MethodSorter.getDeclaredMethods` you can see that it get list of methods by `clazz.getDeclaredMethods()` which does not returns synthetic methods.

So answer is: it is impossible to use `@Before` on interface methods.